# Simple rewrite: www.foo.com to www.foo.com/index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having un authorized error on www.foo.com but www.foo.com/index.php is OK.

So I think i need a .htaccess file to rewrite www.foo.com into www.foo.com/index.php.

Kindly provide the full .htaccess content.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Shouldn't you try to fix the authorization error on `/` first?

Comment: It's a parked domain where the root dir is occupied by a magento copy. Cannot move magento to sub directory for SSL cert reason.

Comment: It there anything currently in the htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /index.php
```

(and no need for "RewriteEngine on" just for this)

Comment: This is exactly how it worked. Thanks.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php